# Collinearity of three points on a curve.

Tags: parametric

In the realm of elliptic curves, the collinearity of three points is of a fundamental importance because this condition allows us to define on the curve a law of Abelian group, the study of which is the subject of endless enigmas and guesses, typical of a fascinating theory.This collinearity of three points, being a geometric concept  is not exclusive to elliptic curves, of course.

On the other hand, it is well known that singular cubics (genus $0$) admit a rational parameterization with a rational parameter (*non-singular cubics, genus $1$, admit also a rational parameterization but with a transcendental parameter, the function $\wp (z)$ of Weierstrass*).

I want here post a question joining the concepts of parameter and collinearity. By instance, for the case of a cusp cubic defined by $$(x,y)=(t^2,t^3)$$ it is proved that $t_1t_2t_3=1$ is equivalent to the fact that the points $P_i=(t_i^2,t_i^3);\space i=1,2,3$ are collinear.

Let now $P_i(x_i,y_i);\space i=1,2,3$ be three points of the nodal cubic defined by
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{4t}{(1-t)^2},\frac{4t(1+t)}{(1-t)^3}\right)$$

**Prove that $$P_1,P_2,P_3\text{ are collinear} \iff \frac {1}{t_1}+\frac {1}{t_2}+\frac {1}{t_3}= 0$$**

[image]

Comment: Collineatity is equivalent to take two pontis, joing them with a strength line, and take the three in that line. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4c%28c%2B1%29%2F%281-c%29%5E3-4a%28a%2B1%29%2F%281-a%29%5E3%3D%284b%28b%2B1%29%2F%281-b%29%5E3-4a%28a%2B1%29%2F%281-a%29%5E3%29%2F%284b%2F%281-b%29%5E2-4a%2F%281-a%29%5E2%29%284c%2F%281-c%29%5E2-4a%2F%281-a%29%5E2%29

Comment: @sinbadh: Thanks for your comment; I edit for you the question,